# Android: Dropbox access token from account credentials

Tags: android, authentication, dropbox, dropbox-api

For an experiment I'd like to make it as convenient for the users as possible to submit their data. I figured a good way of doing this would be to create a dedicated dropbox account which is hardcoded into the app and allows the user to submit data without any account required for himself.

My question: Is there a way to obtain an access token from the dropbox API with just having username + password at hand (which would be hard coded into the app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is "service account" or two-legged Oauth. Unfortunately according to Dropbox they do not have it: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201943685-OAuth-2-0-Server-to-server-authentication

Comment: Mhm. In that post he says one can use the access token `indefinitely` so maybe I just provision the app with one of these tokens?!

Comment: In theory yes, it should work as well, but it is not as reliable as a service account